# Intermittent limited access to network share over VPN

Tags: windows-7, vpn, network-share

I'm looking for ideas for what to check.

I've got a user that has issues when she connects to our network over VPN, but never has issues when she's connected in the office.  The issue is with one of the network shared folders.  When she connects over VPN, sometimes it only allows her access to just one folder inside that shared folder, but at other times it gives her full access to all the folders inside the shared folder.  Her computer has Windows 7 on it.

What I've had her try when this happens is to try disconnecting the share drive after connecting to the VPN, and then reconnecting it--and even having her try this using different drive letters.  That did not solve the problem for her.

I've also tried having her local user profile recreated, but the issue is still happening.

I'm not sure what else to check or try.

Comment: Can you clarify: Is she getting an access denied message when trying to access the share?

Comment: Sorry, there's no access denied message.  The other folders just don't even show up.  When it happens, she only sees one folder that she's able to access.

Comment: It give her full access or she just *see* them ? As it's the Server that hide folder she have no access. You need a FS 2008+ from memory.

Comment: Sounds like a caching issue with offline files.  That's where I'd check first, unless this share is part of DFS replication.  If it's part of DFS replication, check there as well.

Comment: I thinking that looking at issues with the caching of offline files might be the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

The specific folder that is viewable over the network is probably set to an offline folder in Sync Center. I am having the same issue. I believe this happens when Windows detects it as a slow connection, it goes into offline mode. This can be changed in Sync Center settings. In my case, the checkbox is greyed out, not allowing me to change. I am currently researching how to change it using Local Policies, but disabling offline files altogether just may be easier.